# WordPress Front End AJAX Login with Redirects

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, redirect

I have the following code which works beautifully, allowing users to login on the front end, the be redirected to the home page.

Could someone explain what is necessary to do so I may redirect users to different pages based on their user role? For one example, I want the administrators to be redirected to the WordPress dashboard while another user role will be redirected to a specified page.

Functions file:

```
function ajax_login_init(){

wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Verifying user info, please wait...')
));

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}

function ajax_login(){

// First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

// Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
$info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$info['remember'] = true;

$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
}

die();
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Perform AJAX login on form submit
$('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
    $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
        data: { 
            'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
            'username': $('form#login #username').val(), 
            'password': $('form#login #password').val(), 
            'security': $('form#login #security').val() },
        success: function(data){
            $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
            if (data.loggedin == true){
                document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```